# How do I  remove a printer?

Tags: 11.10, printing

I had problems with my HP deskjet d1360 in Ubuntu 11.10. To resolve the issue I downloaded the hplip from the HP website. By this a new printer entry was created, which works. Unfortunately  the broken entry is still there and is selected as default everytime I print. How to remove the broken entry?

Comment: There is a bug in the GUI:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/324684 I was not able to make changes to the first printer I added via the GUI or the webpage. However this command:
<code>
sudo lpadmin -x HPLaserColor
</code> Worked for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Applications - system settings - printers. The printer window will now open, in the printer window select unlock in the top right hand corner, type in your password when asked. After you have entered your password you will see the lock button has changed to unlock. Now simply click on the minus sing under the printer. The minus sign is next to the plus sign at the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 9):

If you looking for a command to delete a printer use this (replace "HPLaserColor" with your printer name to delete):

```
sudo lpadmin -x HPLaserColor
```

Comment: Worked in 12.10. The '-' button on the system settings page wasn't working but this fixed it.